# javascript sort array by inside data

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array by his inside first element data .
my array looks something like that

```
arr = [[0,"lol"][6,"yo"][5,"comon"]]
```

After the sorting I need it to be like that :

```
[[0,"lol"][5,"comon"][6,"yo"]]
```

0 , 5 , 6 suppose to order the cells and they data they have is irrelevent.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a[0] - b[0] });

Comment: please post your code?

Comment: @Givi please place an answer so i can check it

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael I updated my answer, made it more effective... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this... 
[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/6wQZg/5/)

**I made ​​some changes...**

1. Corrected the mistake :
   `// before that I'm checking arrays and not a values of it...

   (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)) to (!isNaN(a[0]) && !isNaN(b[0]))`
2. and to ignore case...
   `aa = a[0].toString().toLowerCase();
   bb = b[0].toString().toLowerCase();`

**===========================================================**

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa, bb;
    if (!isNaN(a[0]) && !isNaN(b[0])) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    } else {
        aa = a[0].toString().toLowerCase();
        bb = b[0].toString().toLowerCase();
        return (aa == bb) ? 0 : (aa < bb) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in my opinion testing for non-numeric is overkill given the input was specified as numeric. Still, I guess +1 for showing a way to handle non-numerics...

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated my answer, making it a more versatile... ;)

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cttxy/2/)

```
var arr = [[0,"lol"],[6,"yo"],[5,"comon"]];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

Comment: It needs to be `return a[0] - b[0]`; the sort function isn't supposed to return a boolean.

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael Yes, it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to sort your array..

```
var arr = [[0,"lol"],[6,"yo"],[5,"comon"]];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[0] == b[0]) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```